# How to initialize an array of record in VHDL?

Tags: arrays, vhdl, record

I'm initializing an array of record which also contains a string. I'm getting an error HDLCompiler:806 Line 109: Syntax error near "text_passages" (Last line in the code below). What's the correct way of initialization?

```vhdl
type text_info is
    record
        text : string(1 to 15);
        x: integer;
        y: integer;
    end record;
constant init_text_info: text_info := (text => "               ", x => 0, y => 0);
type text_info_array is array(natural range <>) of text_info;
```

My declaration and initialization is as follows

```vhdl
signal text_passages : text_info_array(0 to 1) := (others => init_text_info);
text_passages(0) <= (text => "This is a Test.", x => 50, y => 50);
```

Comment: Removing the second paren in the tex_passages(0) assignment removes the ability of your readers to replicate the answer even should they produce their own [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've got an extra bracket at the end of your last line, but apart from that, it's fine. (I doubt the error message you report is caused by that bracket.) The last line should be:

```
text_passages(0) <= (text => "This is a Test.", x => 50, y => 50);
```

---

An [MCVE]:

```
entity E is
end entity ;

architecture A of E is

  type text_info is
    record
        text : string(1 to 15);
        x: integer;
        y: integer;
    end record;
  constant init_text_info: text_info := (text => "               ", x => 0, y => 0);
  type text_info_array is array(natural range <>) of text_info;
  signal text_passages : text_info_array(0 to 1) := (others => init_text_info);

begin

  text_passages(0) <= (text => "This is a Test.", x => 50, y => 50);

end architecture A;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4ARJ

(It's always best to submit an MCVE.)

Comment: It compiles on each of the four VHDL simulators on EDA Playground (VCS, Incisive, Riviera Pro, GHDL) with no error. Try it. What simulator are you using?

Comment: Or are you trying to put the line beginning with `text_passages(0)` before the `begin`, ie within the _declarative region_ of the architecture?

Comment: I put it before begin. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've sorted it. This is why an MCVE is always a good idea: the error was effectively in code you didn't include in your question.